# Indexing on a mostly 0 column not working

Tags: postgresql, partial-index

I've been having troubles with trying to use an index on my table.

For table `items`, I have a column named `market`. If `market` = 0, then it's not for sale - if it's a value greater than 0 (for example, 100), it is for sale, for $100.

However, I have tens of millions of rows of items, that aren't for sale. There's probably around 1000 or so items at sale (with a price) at a time.

I'm trying to have a fast query for selecting all rows in which market is greater than 0;

`SELECT market FROM items WHERE market > 0`.

However, this takes relatively long and uses a SEQ scan instead of the index I have on `market`. Any help would be appreciated, or another approach to my question.

Comment: Please post the table definition with indexes for your table `items`

Comment: Works for me.  Did you VACUUM ANALYZE, and what version of PostgreSQL are you using?  If you want help interpreting the EXPLAIN ANALYZE, you will need to show it to us.

Comment: Sure, I'm using ver 11 and here's what I get:

`[<Record QUERY PLAN='Seq Scan on items  (cost=0.00..323343.44 rows=12443505 width=75) (actual time=1811.756..1811.763 rows=1 loops=1)'>, <Record QUERY PLAN='  Filter: (market <> 0)'>, <Record QUERY PLAN='  Rows Removed by Filter: 12506034'>, <Record QUERY PLAN='Planning Time: 0.240 ms'>, <Record QUERY PLAN='Execution Time: 1811.795 ms'>]` - sorry about the format, I'm printing it with Python

Answer (score 1):

You can write partial index on your table `items`

```
CREATE INDEX idx_items_inactive
ON customer(market)
WHERE market> 0;
```

It will use Index scan in case of query mentioned in the question

Comment: Unfortunately I tried this and it still uses SEQ scan... however, I haven't put this into production yet. This means that all the items are currently unlisted (market = 0), except a few that I'm testing with (so this means, about 5 items that have market > 0 in 8 million rows.) Could this possibly be affecting it?

Comment: Do you have any other index on this table

Comment: I normally 1 other index in this table - index for user_id, as I need to assign each item to a user.

However, I removed it for testing purposes and it still seems to show the same thing - a SEQ scan query in EXPLAIN ANALYZE.